# How to split data from two columns in one table into multiple columns of a result table

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have been trying to get mySQL query to work for a large database that I have. I have (lets say) two tables Table_One and Table_Two. Table_One has three columns Type, Anima and TestID and Table_Two has 2 columns Test_Name and Test_ID. Example with values is below:

```
           TABLE_ONE


Type             Animal        TestID       
-----------------------------------------
Mammal             Goat           1
Fish               Cod            1
Bird               Chicken        1
Reptile            Snake          1
Bird               Crow           2
Mammal             Cow            2
Bird               Ostrich        3
```

---

```
Table_Two
Test_name         TestID       
-------------------------
Test_1              1
Test_1              1
Test_1              1
Test_1              1
Test_2              2
Test_2              2
Test_3              3
```

---

In Table_One all types come under one column and the values of all Types (Mammal, Fish, Bird, Reptile) come under another column (Animals). Table_One and Two can be linked by Test_ID

I am trying to create a table such as shown below:

```
Test_Name      Bird      Reptile      Mammal          Fish
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Test_1         Chicken    Snake        Goat            Cod
Test_2         Crow                    Cow
Test_3         Ostrich
```

This should be my final table. The approach I am currently using is to make multiple instances of Table_One and using joins to form this final table. So the column Bird, Reptile, Mammal and Fish all come from a different copy of Table_one.

For e.g

```
Select
Test_Name As 'Test Case Name',
Table_Bird.Animal AS 'Birds',
Table_Mammal.Animal AS 'Mammal',
Table_Reptile.Animal AS 'Reptile,
Table_Fish.Animal AS 'Fish'
From Table_One
INNER JOIN TABLE_Two AS Table_Bird
On Table_One.TestID = Table_Bird.TestID
INNER JOIN TABLE_Two AS Table_Mammal
On Table_One.TestID = Table_Mammal.TestID
INNER JOIN TABLE_Two AS Table_Reptile
On Table_One.TestID = Table_Reptile.TestID
INNER JOIN TABLE_Two AS Table_Fish
On Table_One.TestID = Table_Fish.TestID
Where Table_Bird.Type LIKE 'Birds'
AND Table_Mammal.Type LIKE 'Mammals'
AND Table_Reptile.Type LIKE 'Reptiles'
AND Table_Fish.Type LIKE 'Fish'
```

The problem with this query is it only works when all entries for Birds, Mammals, Reptiles and Fish have some value. If one field is empty as for Test_Two or Test_Three, it doesn't return that record. I used Or instead of And in the WHERE clause but that didn't work as well.

I would really appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Why does `Table_Two` have full duplicates? Shouldn't it have only three rows?

Comment: Your `Table_Two` is redundant.  Can we assume that there is a 1:1 mapping between the `TestID` and `Test_name` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and move you WHERE up to the JOIN condition and make it LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN - Like this:

```
Select
    Test_Name As 'Test Case Name',
    Table_Bird.Animal AS 'Birds',
    Table_Mammal.Animal AS 'Mammal',
    Table_Reptile.Animal AS 'Reptile,
    Table_Fish.Animal AS 'Fish'
From Table_One
LEFT JOIN TABLE_Two AS Table_Bird ON Table_One.TestID = Table_Bird.TestID AND Table_Bird.Type LIKE 'Birds'
LEFT JOIN TABLE_Two AS Table_Mammal ON Table_One.TestID = Table_Mammal.TestID AND Table_Mammal.Type LIKE 'Mammals'
LEFT JOIN TABLE_Two AS Table_Reptile ON Table_One.TestID = Table_Reptile.TestID AND Table_Reptile.Type LIKE 'Reptiles'
LEFT JOIN TABLE_Two AS Table_Fish ON Table_One.TestID = Table_Fish.TestID AND Table_Fish.Type LIKE 'Fish'
```

Comment: Hey Morten.

Thanks for the response. I tried left join before posting the comment but that didn't work. shifting the conditions from the WHERE clause to the joins did the trick. My query now works. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing your `INNER JOIN` statements by `LEFT JOIN`.